# How can I get schema name from sequelize models?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm using sequelize 6.3.3 and sequelize-typescript:2.0.0-beta.0 and I'm already able to get the table name with `user.constructor.tableName`. How can I get the table schema? Or the table with schema already included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for the solution, in sequelize 6 this is the answer `user.constructor.options.schema`

Answer (score 2):

i solved this problem using this:
MyModel.getTableName().schema